# Failed to link with standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to link `libprotobuf` to my project. In order to do that, I already compiled libprotobuf to a dynamic libray, which is on my library path.

However, when compiling with `/MD`, I get the following error from the linker:

```
 3>libprotobuf.lib(int128.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in component.obj [C:\Projekte\P3D-ECS\p3d_e
```

So, I changed the flag from `/MD` to `/MT`, and those disappeared. However, now the linker is failing to link the standard library, and cannot find symbols like `std::basic_ostream`, with a lot of errors like this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA_JPEBD_J@Z)
```

I have already tried adding `libcmt` and `MSVCRT` to my linker dependencies, without success.

It seems that my DLL simply fails to compile with the `/MT` flag, regardless of linking `libprotobuf` or not. **What am I missing?**

Comment: Did you (re-)build *everything* with the CRT dynamically linked?

Comment: Yes, i deleted the whole build folder, and did a clean rebuild - nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure every library and the exe are built with /MD (or /MDd in debug), i.e dynamic link to CRT? Your error message seems to suggest a mismatch between static and dynamic linking...

Comment: The issue is that libprotobuf is linked with `/MT` so I have to compile with `/MD` too in order to link it statically

Comment: Okay, so I am linking my DLL with another library with is compiled with `/MD`, and it seems causes the problem. Is there any way to link two libraries, where one was compiled with `/MD` and one with `/MT` ?

Comment: I found a solution, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the protobuf CMakeLists, I found the following solution:

```
-Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF
```

Had to be passed to the cmake command, to make protobuf use `/MD` instead of `/MT`.